# JQuery multiple functions not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a website using JQuery to display HTML returned from an AJAX call.
Upon clicking a button, the following JS function is called:

```
function example(...) {
    get_ajax_and_display(...);
    show_hidden_div(...);
}
```

The first function `get_ajax_and_display()` makes an ajax call, and on success, calls `$("#ex_div").html(ajax_response)` to set the `innerHTML` of `ex_div` to whatever was returned from the ajax call. In particular, that returned html contains a `<span id='ex_span' style="display: none">`.

The second function `show_hidden_div()` calls `$("#ex_span").show()` in order to display that span.

However, the second function call fails, as `$("#ex_span")` seems to be undefined, even though the first function already created it.

Does the `.html(ajax_response)` not actually get set until the `example(...)` function returns?

I call the 2 inner functions separately in other parts of my code and they work fine on their own.

Why can't I call them like this?

Comment: use 'on' method to display the div which is added by ajax response

Comment: As an update, I have much better code using Deferred objects from the `$.post()` function. Required a bit of a refactor, but the result is much better than using the deprecated `async` parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add async to your ajax call as follows

```
url: "url.php?" + params,
async: false,
dataType: "html",
```

Comment: I will a bool parameter to the JS function to have the AJAX be async true/false, then I could have it by sync when I need it to

Comment: Yep, with a parameter I can set in the function call whether or not the AJAX is async. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Trigger `show_hidden_div();` in the `success` function of your ajax call, ajax is asynchronous so `show_hidden_div()` triggers first and then when ajax is complete the div is appended to the page

Comment: Ahhh, that makes a lot of sense, thanks for pointing that out! However, these 2 functions are used on their own separately in other parts of the site, so I can't do what you suggested unfortunately

Comment: you know javascript is executed globally on the page don't you?,is it that difficult to just trigger show_hidden_div in the success function?